# Failed to use imwrite() in Qt Creator in Debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I used `imwrite()` function in Qt Creator. I failed to run the code in Debug mode,while successfully in Release mode.
 I wrote a test program.The followings is what I have done:
 First to use `OpenCV`, I added the following code in .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\include
LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\*.lib
```

Then I added a Push Button. The slot function is:

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Mat img;
    img=imread("F:\\My_Desktop\\foot1.jpg",0);
    imwrite("F:\\My_Desktop\\result.jpg",img);
    namedWindow("test");
    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Finally, in Release mode, I can successfully read and write the image. However, failed to write in Debug mode. The error information is:

[image: error information]

**UPDATE**

`imread` works in debug mode, for example, I change the slot function into:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Mat img;
    img=imread("F:\\My_Desktop\\foot1.jpg",0);
    namedWindow("test");
    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey(0);
    imwrite("F:\\My_Desktop\\result.jpg",img);

}
```

I can successfully load and `imshow` the image in Debug mode, but when I closed the windows, the same error happened.

The content of lib folder：

[image: my lib]

I have just seen a problem like mine [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24852639/6666850) , but it could not fix mine.

Comment: Does `imread` fail in debug mode`? Is the path to the file you read (and write) absolute in your actual program too?

Comment: You need to link to debug libraries (ending with "d"). Use `LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\*d.lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you included all library using *.lib command. In debug mode if you links with release libraries it fails. It works in release mode cause it links with release libs as it comes first due to string sort. See the image

[image]

Here 2411**d**.lib stands for debug library and 2411.lib stands for release library. I faced this issue and fixed separate linking in debug & release mode. You can either make 2 folders of debug and release libraries or you can mention the library names instead of *.lib.

[change the version for you]

Debug link: LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV2.411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\*‌​d.lib

Release link: LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV2.411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\*‌​2411.lib

**OR**

To separate folder See the images:

**Folder stucture:**

[image]

**Debug Library folder:**

[image]

**Release Library folder:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

If opencv is not built with qt properly please follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library)

Comment: I' ve tried your suggestion, and I modified my .pro:

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\include
#LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\*.lib
CONFIG(debug,debug|release)
{
LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_world310d.lib
}
CONFIG(release,debug|release)
{
LIBS+=D:\Work_Software\OpenCV3.1\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_world310.lib
}`

Comment: I still met the same problem, I have updated my question, my lib folder is showed above.

Comment: it seems you linked with only one lib `o‌​pencv_world310.lib` where are the other libs like opencv_highgui, opencv_imgproc ??? without this imwrite won't work

Comment: have you built opencv with qt compiler ?? if not please follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library

Comment: Yes, my `opencv` version is `opencv3.1`, only need to link `310/310d.lib`.  <br/>And I have added a debugger, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe`. I can use  breakpoint to debug my program in Debug mode, but when the program runs to `imwrite`, the error occur.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571797/application-crashes-when-opening-a-window-qt

Comment: Thanks a lot. The last link does work. When I move the `imwrite` from the slot function to the `main` function , the program could run successfully in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV dll and lib files are differ in terms of CPU architecture (32-64 bit) and Debug-Release mode. if you switch to Debug mode you must use dll and lib files for Debug mode (depends on CPU architecture).